# PHP save dynamic fields to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, field

I have a form with fixed elements like radio button, text boxes, drop downs, etc.

There is also an area of dynamically generated dates and text boxes passes to the Post as an array to be saved into a MYSQL database.

The form is quite big and I would like to give the user the possibility to save it avoiding to have to retype data all the time.

I would also like to give the user the possibility to save their choices by storing a date and a description of their selection.

The problem is that I don't know how to tackle this problem as I don't know how to handle the dynamic part of the form. i am trying to generate a sort of automatic process but I cannot think of a workable solution.

Any idea?

Comment: giving you the solution wouldn't help a lot. I'd recommend doing a `print_r($_POST)` in the PHP script that receives the form data, there you can figure out what to do to read it (like a `foreach` loop)

Comment: Dynamic? Perhaps a one-to-many relation database table?

Answer (score 0):

If by dynamic you refer to xml requests ( ajax ) then you can easily save all the data in session cookies, as this very site does when you're asking a question. :P